# Dragstart event not firing reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

dragstart event isn't firing on chrome browser...I want to set the state to true on mouse drag event. so i add the document.addeventlistener('dragstart', this.dragstart) to the mousedown method like below,

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedown);
}

componentWillUnMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedown);
}

dragstart = () => {
   console.log("dragstart");
}

mousedown = e => {
    console.log("mousedown"); 
    document.addEventListener('dragstart', this.dragstart);
}
```

Could someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: What is `render () {
    mousedown = e => {`? It's not normal JSX construction. You should return components in `render` method

Comment: edited the question. had  a typo

Answer (score 3):

The ondragstart event occurs when the user starts to drag an element or text selection, but I don't think it will fire on a mousedown. As well, the element needs to be draggable.

`<p draggable="true">`

Comment: Thanks. how do i check if the element is dragged?

Comment: This is a pretty good resource that should cover it I think.. [HTML5 Drag and Drop](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)